# 設定の保持のしかた

Tags: c#, wpf

WPFをつかってGUIアプリケーションをつくってみたりしています。
そこで質問なのですが、テキストボックスなどに入力した値を保存して、次の実行時に復元することは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もちろん様々な方法で実現可能ですが、.NETの標準的なユーザー設定の機構としては`Settings.settings`があります。

具体的にはプロジェクトのプロパティに「設定」というページがあり、そこで設定項目の追加・削除・初期値の指定ができます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ここにキーを追加しておくと、プロジェクト内から

```
textBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.項目名;
```

のように値を読み出すことが出来ます。

保存時は

```
Properties.Settings.Default.項目名 = textBox1.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

と項目の設定とファイルへの保存の2ステップになります。

Comment: 試してみたところ思い通りの動作になりました。ありがとうございます。